# eclipse shortcut to remove warning

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am coding an android project and several times it happens that in XML files I end up changing the parent layout from Relative to Linear. When this happens there is a lot of unused code and it is highlighted through warnings (e.g. android:layout_alignParentLeft is not there in Linearlayout - so it gives me a warning that LinearLayout does not have the specified property).

What I want to do is remove all such code with an eclipse shortcut. I searched a couple of websites on Google but could not find anything substantial.

To provide an analogy - we use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to remove all unused imports.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to `Eclipse`, but to `Lint`. If you edit the poject settings, under the tab `Android`, you can find the `Lint` section. There you can change the behaviour you mentioned.

The correct path should be:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking
```

Comment: ok I see what you are saying, but how do I delete all the lines with the warning messages ?

Comment: you look at the list in Lint error checking, you can find, for instance, "unuseful parent". For this entry you can set the Serverity to "ignore" and the warning should disappear. Do the same action for every warning you wanna disable

Comment: no I don't want to disable the warning, I want the whole line with the error message to get deleted.